# MongoDB query combining $and and $in

Tags: collections, mongodb

I am trying to build a query that will look in data.tags with the following results:

'data' objects containing the following tags params ARE returned:

```
tags : [ 'a', 'c' ]
tags : [ 'a', 'd' ]
tags : [ 'b', 'c' ]
tags : [ 'b', 'd' ]
```

and 'data' objects containing the following tags params ARE NOT RETURNED:

```
tags : [ 'a', 'b' ]
tags : [ 'c', 'd' ]
any others
```

The query I am starting with is below, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
db.data.find({ $and : [ {tags: {$in: ['a', 'b']}}, {tags: { $in: ['c', 'd']} } ] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$and is not available until MongoDB 1.9.1 (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and)

I'm using a hosted solution running 1.8.1.